# Yank file path with line no from vim to system clipboard

Tags: vim, clipboard, filepath, yank

I would like to yank -

- A full path to the file, e.g. c:\foo\bar\file.txt:94 with its line no

I would also like to paste it to my system clipboard so i will use '+' register for this.

can you suggest me possible way to do this?

Comment: You could highlight it in visual mode

Comment: Are you trying to yank the `c:\foo\bar\file.txt:94` when you are on line 94 of `c:\foo\bar\file.txt` or are you trying to the contents of the line?

Comment: I am trying to copy `c:\foo\bar\file.txt:94` to my system clipboard

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are trying to yank `c:\foo\bar\file.txt:94` when you are on line  94 of `c:\foo\bar\file.txt` you can use the following statement to set the `+` register to
 `<file_path>:<line_number>`

```
:let @+=expand("%") . ':' . line(".")
```

`expand("%")` - is the current file name
`line(".")` - is the current line number

An example mapping is

```
nnoremap <leader>y :let @+=expand("%") . ':' . line(".")<CR>
```

Comment: If one had selected text, how would one modify this mapping to go about adding that selected text to the beginning of that register (before the path and line no)?

Comment: @mcabrams selected text as in visual selection? Something like `vnoremap <leader>y "+y:let @+=@+.expand("%") . ':' . line(".")<CR>` might work. Yank the visual selection into the `+` register than append file and line number to the end of the register.